# what is the timezone that yahoo uses for stock information

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, yahoo-finance

Sites such as yahoo show historical data for stocks. They show stocks for all different stock markets. When they show information for a day for example the hong kong stock market, are those dates shown at local Hong Kong time? SO for example if I see two stocks on Jan 10th, one is a stock trading on the Hong Kong stock market, and the other is trading on the NYSE, is the Jan 10th of the Hong Kong stock actually a few hours ago before (If I was in living in NY) or is it based on a universal timezone like greentime?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an example webpage?

Comment: https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=GOOGL#symbol=GOOGL;range=1d

Answer (score 1):

Using your example link, I found the corresponding chart for a stock that trades on London Stock Exchange:

https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=RIO.L#symbol=RIO.L;range=1d

As you can see there, the chart runs from ~8:00am to ~4:30pm, and as I write this post it is only 2:14pm Eastern Time.  So clearly this foreign chart is using a foreign time zone.  And as you can see from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_exchange_opening_times), those hours are exactly the London Stock Exchange's hours.

Additionally, the closing price listed above the graph has a timestamp of "11:35AM EST", meaning that the rightmost timestamp in the graph (~4:30pm) is equal to 11:35AM EST.  16:30 - 11:30 = 5 hours = difference between London and New York at this time of year.

So those are two data points showing that Yahoo uses the exchange's native time zone when displaying these charts.