# What is the time zone Yahoo Finance uses for crypto close prices?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, cryptocurrency, yahoo-finance

I am using the yfinance (Yahoo Finance API) library to retrieve crypto prices (e.g. ETH-USD). I am trying to figure out when the next line (i.e. current day or previous day) will be available. In other words: the close time of the previous day is which time in which timezone?

When I examine the ticker graph I can't seem to figure it out. For instance: today ETH-USD's last ['close' price](https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ETH-USD?p=ETH-USD&.tsrc=fin-srch) is listed at 651.814. For some reason my current time on the graph is in UK time zone (although I am in Singapore).

I cannot find the 651.814 time on the graph. As which time/tz is the close price taken?

It's not 12am UK time:
[image]

Also not 5am UK time = midnight NY time:
[image]

[From Yahoo](https://uk.help.yahoo.com/kb/finance-for-web/exchanges-data-providers-yahoo-finance-sln2310.html) help I can only find information about stock exchanges.

I only found [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43180/what-is-the-timezone-that-yahoo-uses-for-stock-information) related to stock markets, but obviously for crypto it's different as trading is continuous.

### Update, some more info

A few hours before 9pm Eastern time, the day goes blank and the next day already shows up. This is 20 Dec 9PM EST:

[image]

Then after 9pm EST, the row fills in and tomorrows disappears:

[image]

The close time is given as 638.29, which is the price roughly around 7pm EST:
[image]

So far, it seems like the data is 2 hours delayed with day ending at 9pm EST. In this case. If there is such a huge delay I may need to find a different API. Also strange that there is a big difference between close and next day open prices. Especially if the market is continuous?

Comment: Could be US Eastern Time (currently UTC-5).

Comment: That's what I thought at first. But in the second graph that doesn't seem fully true. Just trying to figure out what the fastest time is that I can get the correct close price (of a 24h period).

Comment: I just clicked on the *last close* link, and it says "As of 9:06AM GMT. Market open."

Comment: I believe that is just when the last refresh of the current price was (and apparently the day's close has been updated since, perhaps since it's now morning in the US). I'm wondering when the 24h close. So when you ping the historical close data, when was that fixed. I'm using the Yahoo Finance API to get the historical data. https://algotrading101.com/learn/yahoo-finance-api-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update in the question reveals more info, hinting towards a close time of 7:00pm EST, which is 00:00 UTC.

Finally, I found a page that refers to UTC for Volume referencing.

Still that leaves a 2 hour gap until the data appears... which is quite a huge delay.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to retrieve the data at 23:59 UTC... then it dissapears for 2 hours...

Comment: Do we know whether it's 7pm EST (0:00 UTC) and 7pm EDT (23:00 UTC), or 7pm EST and 8pm EDT (0:00 UTC)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is based on GMT (Greenwich mean time).

Answer (score 0):

It is the British Summer Time (BST). That is what it shows under the cost of the coin on the Yahoo Finance page for any of the Cryptocurrencies.

Comment: How does it look like in the winter? Perhaps you can find out with the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) - it seems hard to believe it uses BST then.